# Public IP Address from Mobile

Tags: ios, iphone, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, ip-address

I want to get the public IP address from my mobile app. So, I tried multiple approaches and finally, I decided to go for **http://checkip.amazonaws.com/**.

So, Can I use this endpoint in my app? Or Should I get the license/approval from AWS?

Comment: What do you mean by get public IP of mobile app does it mean where it is hosted ? or the end user who is using the app ? Kindly elaborate ?

Comment: First, this is a serverfault network question.  Second, if you haven't apply a dedicate IP for your connection,  then dynamic IP will be assigned. Your app will lost connection to your endpoint when the IP reassigned. .

Comment: @SritharRajendran It is a free service by aws guys. You don't have to take any license.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have that much specific knowledge of the endpoint you've mentioned on amazon, but you could do this yourself using a STUN server. 3CX (a producer of a software based PBX telephone system) have this document outlining what a STUN server is:
https://www.3cx.com/pbx/what-is-a-stun-server/

But basically speaking it allows you to find out what routes an external device could use as an IP address for you (your externally visible IP). If you wanted to set up your own it should certainly be possible. There are quite a few STUN server projects on GitHub that have fairly open licenses, so you could set up an AWS instance with one running on it, and then you'd never have to ask permission.

However, if somebody else is aware of the licensing agreement on the endpoint you've mentioned, it may be the quicker way. This might be the better long term solution though; however, I don't really understand enough about your project / use case to know for sure.